# How do I run a Sinatra application on G-WAN?

Tags: ruby, rubygems, sinatra, rack, g-wan

I'm trying to write a Ruby web application and I want to use the functionality offered by Sinatra.

I used this code:

```
  require 'rubygems'
  require 'sinatra'

  get '/' do
      'Hello, world!'
  end
```

I typed localhost:8080/?hello.rb in my browser and I received an error message that the script is unable to find sinatra.
I also tried to run the sinatra app using this command:

```
  ruby hello.rb
```

and this time it worked!
So I suspect the problem is not in my code, but in the way I'm using G-WAN to serve the Ruby script.

Answer (score 3):

Sinatra expects to be run by a rack-compatible server, which G-Wan is apparently not. When you run script manually it is being run by a WEBrick server that comes bundled with Ruby. Examples of compatible servers are [thin](http://code.macournoyer.com/thin/), [unicorn](http://unicorn.bogomips.org/) or apache/nginx with [phusion passenger](https://www.phusionpassenger.com/)

Comment: Do you know any Ruby web framework that doesn't require rack compatibility? Or can you suggest how can make G-WAN rack-compatible?

Answer (score 2):

`Ruby` (like `Java` or `PHP`) probably uses configuration files and/or environment variables to specify where to find packages, modules and libraries.

While G-WAN received similar requests for `asm, C, C++, D, Objective-C, Java and C#` support, `Ruby` users did not manifest interest in this area - so far.

If you point to us the relevant Ruby documentation, we will try to add this Ruby feature (just like it was done for the other languages).

Comment: I'm willing to collaborate with you on this issue. Please provide some me with some contact information.